# Need help with onclick syntax in classic asp environment

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

can't seem to get the syntax right in order to pass the AttID variable. This line of code is in a for loop so I have to print using vbs response.write and not just straignt html.

```
Response.Write "<TD class=alt><input type=button onclick=deleteRecordAtt(AttID) value=remove></TD></TR>"
```

Comment: Are you getting script errors in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done VBScript in 8+ years, but you might want to try:

```
Response.Write "<td class=""alt""><input type=""button"" onclick=""deleteRecordAtt(AttID) value=""remove"" /></td>"
```

This would give you the more accepted html attribute quoting.

Also, your AttID variable is a client script variable?  If not, you'd need to concat the server variable inline, e.g.

```
...onclick=""deleteRecordAtt(" & AttID & ")""...
```

Comment: just a note: I had to include: (" & AttID & ") for it to work.